# Prometheus query_range performance

Tags: prometheus

We have two Prometheus systems, one in Production and one is staging. On production, some of the prometheus queries are timing out when queried via Grafana. (it's taking more than 1 min)

Some of differences between the two systems I observed are -

Prod is running 1.8.2 version of Prometheus, staging is running 2.1.0 
Prod has overall 9.3 billion data points, staging has 1.3 billion.
Prod has about 10k samples ingested every 5 mins, for staging it is 6k every 5 mins.

Questions -

1. Is the query_range performance dependant on the size of the data in Prometheus or the rate of ingestion?
2. The queries work when we use a higher step/ lower resolution, but we really need a 1 second granularity for doing some comparison.  Would the query performance improve when we move to Prometheus 2.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

> Prod has about 10k samples ingested every 5 mins, for staging it is 6k every 5 mins.

This would be a tiny Prometheus, but your numbers don't add up. At 10k/5m that's 33/s which would take about 9 years to reach 9.3B samples. I don't think you're telling me everything.

> Is the query_range performance dependant on the size of the data in Prometheus or the rate of ingestion?

The size of the data.

> The queries work when we use a higher step/ lower resolution, but we really need a 1 second granularity for doing some comparison. Would the query performance improve when we move to Prometheus 2.1.0?

That's getting into profiling, which is possible but tricky to do with metrics.

Comment: Well, for the total number of samples I was looking at the value of prometheus_local_storage_ingested_samples_total which is at 9.75 Bil as of now.  In about a half day this number grew 0.45 Bil.   And rate(prometheus_local_storage_ingested_samples_total[5m]) is about 9.6K.  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: That's 9.6k per second or 2.9M per 5 minutes. Still not large.

Comment: I think the main question is why the queries are taking more than 1 min.  Can you please provide pointers to any tips/tools for profiling the queries?

Comment: That's not the question you asked, and if you're wondering about a query it best to post a new question with the query.

Comment: Got it, I missed that :)